# Editable row in rails using java script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to make each row editable in table. For this I place rows with text_fields in each bellow the row with table data.

```
<style>
  .dtr{
    display:none;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container" align="center">
    <h1>Products Description</h1>
  </div>
  <br />
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Product Description</th>
        <th scope="col">Brand Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @csv_table.each do |row| %>
        <tr class="mtr">
          <% row.each do |key, value| %>
            <%unless key == "id"%>
              <td class="value"><%= value %></td>
            <%end%>
          <% end %>

          <td>
            <div class="edit">
              <%=link_to "Edit",class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
            <div class="delete">
              <%=link_to "Delete",class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="dtr">
          <td>
            <%= text_field_tag :login_aei2, "", class: 'form-control' %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= text_field_tag :login_aei3, "", class: 'form-control' %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= text_field_tag :login_aei4, "", class: 'form-control' %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%=link_to "Save", remote: true, class: 'form-control' %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <%end%>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".edit").click(function(){
      debugger;
      var mtr = this.closest(".mtr");
      mtr.style.display = "none";
      mtr.nextElementSibling.style.display="inline";
      // this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none';
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I click on edit button current row become hidden and the row with input field get shown but the problem is, it shows only in area of table data not in whole row. please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need that each row have a "edit" button or trigger?

Comment: yes each row will have edit button

Answer (score 0):

So when the user click on "edit", its necessary to know exactly what Info has been clicked, in order to update to the database, and in order to show and hide the infos.

The changes that I've made is based on a **demo-data** that I've created to develop this solution:

> @csv_table = [ {id:3, product: "Product", description: "Description",
>   brand:"Brand", action: "Action" }, {id:4, product: "Product2",
>   description: "Description2", brand:"Brand2", action: "Action2" }]

This is so called "Array of Hashes", and I thought that was what you were using too.

In the complete code, as we iterate throught the array, we can see two values that are **name**, and **value**. I used "value" instead of id, because I didnt want to cause a html conflict. So you can see in the code this:

```
<% value = row[:id] %>
```

And this

```
<% name = key[0] %>
```

Then each row has the field, and has the info (but one of them is hidden), like so:

```
<td class="value">
     <a id=<%= "info_#{name}#{value}" %> class="info <%= "info_dtr#{value}" %>" name=<%= name %> value=<%= value %>><%= row[name]  %></a>
     <%= text_field_tag :login_aei, "", class: "form-control field field_dtr#{value}", id: "field_#{name}#{value}"  %>
</td>
```

Can you notice that the id it has name and value? In that way we can tell JQuery to look for the field we have clicked. For example info_product1, and field_product1, and set it to hide(); or show();. Below is the complete code, these are mostly javascript and html tricks, so you can try to play around a little bit:

Ruby + Html:

```
<style>
.dtr{
 display:none;
}

</style>
<div class="container" align="center">
    <h1>Products Description</h1>
</div><br />
<table class="table table-striped" border=2 style="border: 2px solid;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Product Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Brand Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% @csv_table.each_with_index do |row, i|%>
            <% value = row[:id] %> 
                <tr class="mtr">
                    <% row.each_with_index do |key, j| %>
                        <% name = key[0] %>
                        <% unless j==0 %>
                            <td class="value">
                                <a id=<%= "info_#{name}#{value}" %> class="info <%= "info_dtr#{value}" %>" name=<%= name %> value=<%= value %>><%= row[name]  %></a>
                                <%= text_field_tag :login_aei, "", class: "form-control field field_dtr#{value}", id: "field_#{name}#{value}"  %>
                            </td>
                          <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                        <td>
                            <%= link_to "Save", {}, remote: true, class: 'form-control save', 'value' => value   %>
                            <div class="delete"><%=link_to "Delete",class: 'form-control'%></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".field").hide();
});
$(".info").click(function(event){
    console.log("info");
    name = $(this).attr("name");
    id = $(this).attr("value");
    console.log($(this).attr("value"));

    $("#info_" + name + id).hide();
    $("#field_" + name + id).show();
});

$(".save").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // { .. if saves}
    console.log("salvar");
    id = $(this).attr("value");

    $(".field_dtr" + id).hide();
    $(".info_dtr" + id).show();           
});
```

Comment: Thank for your effort. But it is not working .Thank you very much again for your help.